# From the $n$-qubit state $|ψ_0⟩$, how do we find an orthonormal basis $\{|ψ_i⟩\}$ that includes $|ψ_0⟩$ via the Gram-Schmidt process?

Tags: qiskit, programming, textbook-and-exercises

From the n-qubit pure state $|\psi_0\rangle$, how do we find an orthonormal basis $\{|\psi_i\rangle\},i\in[0,2n−1]$ that includes the state $|\psi_0\rangle$ using the Gram-Schmidt process?

Is there any program code which can we run on qiskit?

I'm doing my masters and Quantum is a new topic for me so kindly guide me.

Comment: Create a set $V = \{ v_1 = |\psi_0\rangle, v_2, \cdots, v_{2^n}$ where $v_2, v_3,...$ are some arbitrary but linear independent vectors (also linear independent to $v_1 = |\psi_0 \rangle$ then start the Gram–Schmidt process https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process#The_Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process

Comment: Once you do that then you can use Python's Numpy library to do QR decomposition ( which uses Gram Schmidt is underneath) to get Q, which is what you are looking for. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.qr.html

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no code available in Qiskit yet. A respective contribution would be much appreciated.
You can follow the responses above which explain how to find a Gram-Schmidt basis.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about Gram-Schmidt process support, but you can easily use Qiskit to create an orthonormal basis that includes some state $|\psi_0\rangle$. Just create a quantum circuit that maps $|0^{\otimes n}\rangle$ to $|\psi_0\rangle$. The vectors of the matrix representation of this circuit form an orthonormal basis, and  $|\psi_0\rangle$ is the first one.

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.quantum_info.operators import Operator
from numpy import around

n = 2

# Create a random n-qubit state for demonstration
from qiskit.quantum_info import random_statevector
psi = random_statevector(2 ** n)

circ = QuantumCircuit(n)
circ.iso(psi, list(range(n)), [])

# Get the unitary of the circuit:
op = Operator(circ)

# Get ride of differences due to global phases:
# Note: for simplicity we assume that the first element of Ψ_0 is non-zero
factor = op.data[0][0] / psi.data[0]
matrix = op.data / factor

# Now, print the results: 
print('Ψ_0:')
print(around(psi, 3))

print('Orthonormal basis:')
for column in matrix.T:
    print(around(column, 3))
```

Sample output:

```
Ψ_0:
[ 0.012+0.1j    0.001-0.648j -0.554-0.171j -0.172-0.452j]

Orthonormal basis:
[ 0.012+0.1j    0.001-0.648j -0.554-0.171j -0.172-0.452j]
[-0.633-0.136j -0.095-0.033j  0.478+0.072j -0.285-0.505j]
[-0.013-0.115j -0.002+0.746j -0.481-0.148j -0.149-0.393j]
[ 0.73 +0.157j  0.11 +0.038j  0.415+0.062j -0.247-0.438j]
```